# how to hover URL link and change display image

Tags: html, css

how to make below happen? hover the different link and change the image on the right. not hover anything will show default image.

[image]

Comment: Did you study javascript? Try using jquery, it is pretty straightforward.

Comment: I am thinking which method I should use, Javascript, css or jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#a1:hover ~ #div{
background-image:url("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height:500px;
}

#a2:hover ~ #div{
background-image:url("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height:500px;
}

#a3:hover ~ #div{
background-image:url("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height:500px;
}
```

```html
<a id='a1' href="#">link 1</a>
<a id='a2' href="#">link 2</a>
<a id='a3' href="#">link 3</a>
<div id='div'></div>
```

Comment: oops sorry, I edit the wrong message

Comment: please change it back

Comment: Thank you. Your original question didn't list js as a tag thus I provided you with a css only solution

Comment: I will go for CSS, thanks a lot!

Comment: look into both + and ~

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Add a class to each link and set a background image with css like below:

**CSS**

```
.link-one {
   background: url(***image url one***)
}

.link-two {
   background: url(***image url two***)
}
```

And so on.

**Option 2**

Make individual `<img>` tags for each image. And in css go like this:

**CSS**

```
  .img {
       display: none;
    }
    .link-one:hover img {
       display:block;
    }
```